# How to add correctly 2 items in this JSON? - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I must save x2 the same data fields (`nif` and `name`) at the same time in the DB.

With 1 field (`nif`) it works perfectly and save x2 rows in the DB with different info, so the JSON works, but adding the 2th field (`name`) it just save the `nif` value in all the fields.

I don't understand so much the JSON and his syntax logic, but I think the problem is how I wrote it in the controller.

P.D. No, I can't put `EnviarCurriculumPreguntas::create` x2 in a row because that's not the purpose of this code, so I'm using a JSON instead.

##### `EnviarCurriculum.php`

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EnviarCurriculum extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'table';

    protected $primaryKey = 'ID_table';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nif',
        'name'
    ];

    public function getRepeatedFields()
    {
       return json_decode($this->nif);
       return json_decode($this->name);
    }
}
```

##### `EnviarCurriculumController.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\enviarCurriculum;

use App\EnviarCurriculum;
use App\Configuracion;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EnviarCurriculumController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('enviar_curriculum', ['EnviarCurriculum' => new EnviarCurriculum()]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('enviar_curriculum', ['EnviarCurriculum' => new EnviarCurriculum()]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
         foreach (request('nif', 'name') as $val) {
            EnviarCurriculum::create(['nif' => $val, 'name' => $val]);
        }
    }
}
```

##### `enviar_curriculum.blade.php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ route("store") }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        
        <div>
           <input type="text" name="nif[]" id="nif">

           <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name">
        </div>

        <br>

        <div>
           <input type="text" name="nif[]" id="nif">

           <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name">
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: public function getRepeatedFields()
    {
       return json_decode($this->nif);
       return json_decode($this->name);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't have input having the same name without being an array

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ route("store") }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div>
           <input type="text" name="nif[]" id="nif">
           <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
           <input type="text" name="nif[]" id="nif">
           <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your store method loop the array inputs

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $nifs = $request->input('nif', []);
    $names = $request->input('name', []);
    foreach ($nifs as $key => $nif) {
        EnviarCurriculum::create(['nif' => $nif, 'name' => $names[$key]??'']);
    }
}
```

Then fix your `getRepeatedFields()` method to return both decoded fields.

```
public function getRepeatedFields()
{
    return [
        'nifs' => json_decode($this->nif),
        'names' => json_decode($this->name),
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this excelent code and theory to understand it!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
      <input type="text" name="nif[]" id="nif">

       <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name">
```

in name , nif only store the last inserted item please change it as array

Comment: Oops, true! Thanks!